# Square root of the operator $T$

Tags: functional-analysis

Find the positive square root of the operator $T$ on $L^2 ([a,b])$ defined
by $(Tf)(t) =g(t)f(t)$, where $g$ is a positive continuous function on $[a, b]$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: try another multiplication operator.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the square of a multiplication operator.